# おおい / すくない+[noun]は あまりつかいません

Tags: meaning, nuances

I read in [this file](http://www.mlcjapanese.co.jp/Download/Adjectives_Kana.pdf) (p. 7) the two statements :

> すくない+[noun]は あまりつかいません
>
> おおい+[noun]は あまりつかいません

No translation being given, I'm wondering what the meaning of these sentences is. Maybe "I don't use XXX very much." (?) Do they have the same meaning ? Can you give an example ?

Comment: Those are explanations and not example sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @l'électeur said, those are explanations.

It is saying that, in general:

> People don't use **すくない + [noun]** or **おおい + [noun]** (in sentences, etc.) very often.

That's all.

You should notice their use of 「」quotes to show this.